# Why FileNotFoundException is thrown while it exists on linux

Tags: java, linux, file

This is the first time i have encounter such problem with file access by Java on linux. The problem is just like the header says - `FileNotFoundException` is thrown when file actually exists. Moreover application with same configuration (props.txt file) runs like it should on windows.
Let me provide a little bit of console output

```
datasu@dedi2392:~/netcrawler/dkpto$ ls -l
total 20
-rwxrw-rw- 1 datasu datasu  114 Aug  7 15:53 autoupdate
drwxr-xr-x 4 datasu datasu 4096 Aug  8 11:57 data
drwxr-xr-x 2 datasu datasu 4096 Aug  8 11:57 log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 datasu datasu   32 Aug  8 12:44 props.txt
-rwxrw-rw- 1 datasu datasu  126 Aug  8 12:55 propsUpdate
datasu@dedi2392:~/netcrawler/dkpto$ ./propsUpdate
Parent: /usr/home/datasu/netcrawler/dkpto
   1# -> propsUpdate
   2# -> autoupdate
   3# -> props.txt
   4# -> data
   5# -> log
 (No such file or directory)ava.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/home/datasu/netcrawler/dkpto/props.txt
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
        at netcrawler.Autoupdater.readProperties(Autoupdater.java:71)
        at netcrawler.Autoupdater.start(Autoupdater.java:54)
        at netcrawler.Autoupdater.main(Autoupdater.java:47)
datasu@dedi2392:~/netcrawler/dkpto$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
datasu@dedi2392:~/netcrawler/dkpto$
```

and here is Java code responsible for generating that output (at least after calling `./propsUpdate`)

```
private void readProperties(String args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Parent: " + new     File(args).getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
    CommonTools.PrintArray(new File(args).getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().list());
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File(args).getAbsoluteFile())); // this line throws the exception
    stageNumber = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty(PROP_STAGE_NUMBER_KEY, "0"));
}
```

So why the `props.txt` file is not found when it is actually there ?

Comment: Is the correct path really `/usr/home/datasu/`? I don't know your linux/unix version but isn't it usually somehwere at `/home/...`? Especially since you show `~/` in the first line which referrs to the home directory.

Comment: Here is PWD result for you:
datasu@dedi2392:~/netcrawler/dkpto$ pwd -> 
/usr/home/datasu/netcrawler/dkpto

Comment: What is the exact syntax of `args` that you are passing to `readProperties`?

Comment: Try separating the `FileInputStream` from the `new File`
Like this: 
`File file = new File(args)`
`file = file.getAbsoluteFile()`
`FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)`
this way we can get more info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The string "args" probably has a nonprinting character at the end, like a space. You could use String.trim() to remove such characters before using that variable.

Comment: Wow, now that just stupid. I have double checked lunching script for some spaces etc. in filename but nothing was there. HOWEVER trimming the argument made the trick. Thanks for suggestion. Lesson for today: Never trust arguments passed by command line. Is there any way to make VI, VIM to display nonprintables?

Comment: You could always `echo $arg | hexdump -C`

Comment: There was `0x0D0A` sequence and thats i guess carret return right?. Shouldn't it be dropped by the JVM when passing args array to the main? I never had such problem before

Comment: `0d` is a carriage return and `0a` is a newline character.

Comment: @Antoniossss my guess is your `properties.load` is appending the `cr` and `nl`.

Comment: If you show us the shell script, maybe we could see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Wow now thats would be just stupid;/ my properties is actually `java.util.Properties` instance. And moreover that is not possible because it takes `InputStream` as parameter, so it must exist prior calling load method

Answer (score 2):

Is your home folder really this path?

```
/usr/home/datasu
```

`/home/datasu` is where it normally is on linux.

Also, try changing that line to this:

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File(args));
```

If you're calling that as `./propsUpdate ./props.txt` that will work from the current working directory.

Comment: This path is correct, as you can se application starts and the parent folder is listed just fine with such path (check code that generated it)

Comment: Code that you provided was the first version, and I have change it to see the full path to file in the exception

Comment: Please consider the fact that the path is absolute, so working directory should not affect that. Moreover path is created by Java and the same code works just fine on windows.